# Set SSLSocketFactory to JAX-WS web service call on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, weblogic12c, sslsocketfactory

I need to call an external web service endpoint through HTTPS, using an SSL certificate. The right way should be setting a custom SSLSocketFactory using the BindingProvider, but I'm not able to get it working. To get the connection working I have to set a default SSLSocketFactory:

```
 public void secureStoreSignedOffPdf(String filename, byte[] signedOffPdf, URL endpoint, String applicationEnvironmentId) {
    final SSLSocketFactory defaultSslSocketFactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    final SSLSocketFactory wsSslSocketFactory = SslHelper.buildWebServiceSslSocketFactory(applicationEnvironmentId);
    // TODO Fix: this should work only setting the property with BindingProvider (see below)
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(wsSslSocketFactory);

    final StoragePortService storagePortService = new StoragePortService();
    final StoragePort storagePort = storagePortService.getStoragePortSoap11();

    final BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) storagePort;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
                   .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint.toString());
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
                   .put("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", wsSslSocketFactory);

    final StorageRequest storageRequest = new StorageRequest();
    final Document document = new Document();
    document.setContent(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(signedOffPdf, PDF_CONTENT_TYPE)));
    document.setName(filename);

    storageRequest.setOverwrite(true);
    storageRequest.setBaseDocument(document);
    final StorageResponse storageResponse = storagePort.storage(storageRequest);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(defaultSslSocketFactory);
    if (!storageResponse.getReturnCode()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(RESPONSE_OK)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Web service failed with error: "
                                                + storageResponse.getReturnCode()
                                                + " - "
                                                + storageResponse.getReturnMessage());
    }
}
```

If I remove this line:

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", wsSslSocketFactory);
```

The code still works (because I'm using the HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory method). But if in that line I put a wrong SSLSocketFactory, it fails, so it means that putting the factory attribute does something.

What I don't get is the call working without setting the default SSLSocketFactory:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(...)
```

FYI: I've already tried with:

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", wsSslSocketFactory);
```

but it doesn't do anything.